# Why do I keep getting this error while trying to launch my robot with moveit2?

Tags: ros2, moveit, move-group, moveit2

I keep getting the following error and I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong, any direction would be much appreciated.
[image]

I've used moveit setup assistant to get me going initially.

The following is my launch file:

```
import os
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import ExecuteProcess, DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch_ros.actions import Node
import yaml
import xacro



def load_file(package_name, file_path):
    package_path = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
    absolute_file_path = os.path.join(package_path, file_path)
    try:
        with open(absolute_file_path, 'r') as file:
            return file.read()
    except EnvironmentError:
        return None

def load_yaml(package_name, file_path):
    package_path = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
    absolute_file_path = os.path.join(package_path, file_path)
    try:
        with open(absolute_file_path, 'r') as file:
            return yaml.safe_load(file)
    except EnvironmentError:
        return None

def generate_launch_description():
    package_share_dir = get_package_share_directory("kuka_kr210_arm")
    urdf_file = os.path.join(package_share_dir, "urdf", "kr210_.urdf")
    controller_file = os.path.join(package_share_dir, "config", "jtc.yaml")
    kinematics_yaml = load_yaml("kuka_kr210_arm", "config/kinematics.yaml")
    trajectory_execution = {
        "moveit_manage_controllers": True,
        "trajectory_execution.allowed_execution_duration_scaling": 1.2,
        "trajectory_execution.allowed_goal_duration_margin": 0.5,
        "trajectory_execution.allowed_start_tolerance": 0.01,
    }
    moveit_simple_controllers_yaml = load_yaml("kuka_kr210_arm", "config/moveit_controllers.yaml")
    moveit_controllers = {
        "moveit_simple_controller_manager": moveit_simple_controllers_yaml,
        "moveit_controller_manager": "moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager",
    }
    kuka_description_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory('kuka_kr210_arm'))
    xacro_file = os.path.join(kuka_description_path,
                              'urdf',
                              'kr210.urdf.xacro')
    doc = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)
    robot_description_config = doc.toxml()
    robot_description_moveit = {'robot_description': robot_description_config}
    robot_description_semantic_config = load_file("kuka_kr210_arm", "config/kuka_kr210_arm.srdf")
    robot_description_semantic = {"robot_description_semantic": robot_description_semantic_config}
    planning_scene_monitor_parameters = {
        "publish_planning_scene": True,
        "publish_geometry_updates": True,
        "publish_state_updates": True,
        "publish_transforms_updates": True,
        "publish_robot_description": True,
        "publish_robot_description_semantic": True
    }
    with open(urdf_file, 'r') as infp:
        robot_description = infp.read()
    return LaunchDescription(
        [
            ExecuteProcess(
                cmd=["gazebo","--verbose","-s","libgazebo_ros_factory.so",],
                output="screen",
            ),
            Node(
                package="gazebo_ros",
                executable="spawn_entity.py",
                arguments=["-entity","kuka_kr210_arm","-b","-file", urdf_file,],
            ),
            Node(
                package="robot_state_publisher",
                executable="robot_state_publisher",
                output="screen",
                parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description}],
                arguments=[urdf_file],
            ),
            
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="ros2_control_node",
                parameters=[urdf_file, controller_file],
                output={
                    "stdout": "screen",
                    "stderr": "screen",
                },
            ),
            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner",
                arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
            ),

            Node(
                package="controller_manager",
                executable="spawner",
                arguments=["joint_trajectory_controller", "-c", "/controller_manager"],
            ),
            Node(
                package="kuka_kr210_arm",
                executable="kuka_kr210_arm",
                parameters=["publish_robot_description", "publish_robot_description_semantic"]
            ),
            Node(
                package="moveit_ros_move_group",
                executable="move_group",
                output="screen",
                parameters=[
                    robot_description_moveit,
                    robot_description_semantic,
                    kinematics_yaml,
                    trajectory_execution,
                    moveit_controllers,
                    planning_scene_monitor_parameters,
                    ]
            )
        ]
    )
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I would suggest to use OMPL rather than CHOMP unless you have a clear reason to use CHOMP. The majority of MoveIt users choose OMPL.

That should be set similar to this:

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_resources/blob/dad863321cd2ded86a80c8013a821dabf2f72260/panda_moveit_config/launch/demo.launch.py#L47

Comment: Thank you for answering me, I'd like to try your suggestion but unless I don't understand something then from what understanding I need an OMPL file for my robot (in config), correct me if I'm wrong. And the setup assistant doesn't create a file like that, and I'm unsure how I go about creating one that fits my robot.

Comment: I suspect something was broken with `moveit_setup_assistant` recently. Sorry! You can set things up manually by copying the files here:

https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_resources/tree/dad863321cd2ded86a80c8013a821dabf2f72260/panda_moveit_config

In fact, if I were in your shoes, I wouldn't use MoveIt Setup Assistant at all. I'd start from that `panda_moveit_config` package and rename things.

I'd also encourage you to open an issue on the MoveIt2 repo so they/we will be aware of the problem.